# Connect Wayland screenshot tool to ksnip

Tags: wayland, screenshot

We use `ksnip` as a company-standard cross platform screenshot annotation tool.
When switching to Wayland, I can take only screenshots via the portal, which is not very efficient.

Is it possible to launch ksnip automatically after taking a screenshot with the gnome / wayland screenshot tool which is default in Ubuntu 22.04 ?
(how is that tool called?)

Currently, as a workaround, I can take a screenshot, copy to clipboard, open ksnip, annoate, export which is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I will bind an additional shortcut for opening ksnip with the clipboard contents to the following script:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o | ksnip -e -
```

Thus I can take a screenshot using the standard tool, copy to clipboard (Ctrl+C) and press my new short cut (Is used Ctrl+Shift+Alt+K)

An improvement would be to also simulate pressing Ctrl+C in that shortcut.

But `xdotool key 'ctrl+c'` did not work for me.

Remark: There [is currently a small bug in ksnip](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip/issues/741), which makes this working not perfect yet, but overall its a good solution for me.

EDIT :I nthe latest nightly that bug is solved in ksnip.

Comment: The small issue you mentioned should be fixed now in ksnip v1.10.1

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set new shortcut for:

```
ksnip -t
```

Which captures a screenshot and opens/shows it directly in `ksnip` portal. Press share button as your usual workflow.

Btw, there are other ways `ksnip` can be combined in series with other tools as long it can open and save files from command line. Check `ksnip -h`.

2nd option create a script that watches screenshots folder and launches `ksnip` to edit new files. Similar to this one: [Autostart program whenever a file is added to a folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/518457/26246)

Comment: `ksnip -t` is better than nothing, but it captures a full screen screenshot which needs to be cropped later. The wayland tool is already nice, the question is if there can be some postprocessing added. I am also wondering what is the command for the wayland tool, because that does not show up in the short cut list. it's just the "screenshot action"

Comment: @Alex It doesn't look to be separate  tool from gnome-shell. The only approach I could think of right now, is a gnome-shell extension (java-script based) that target and customize that screenshot component. Extend it to open or share captured image with another user set tool.

Comment: I found an okayisch workaround in my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1445519/39966