# Is there a CLI for the default Wayland Screenshot tool? How is that tool called?

Tags: gnome-shell, wayland, screenshot

What is the standard screenshot tool of Wayland?

I configured it here:

[image: Screenshot Config]

But I am wondering if the same interactive screenshot tool can be launched by a terminal command?

(I am trying to solve: [Connect Wayland screenshot tool to ksnip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442468/connect-wayland-screenshot-tool-to-ksnip))

[image: Screenshot tool]

Comment: What you show is the new Gnome screenshot tool, not wayland's. It works is X11 as well.

Comment: Ah, okay, and can this be called via CLI? gnome-screenshot does not work.

Comment: If it has a Graphical User Interface then it isn't what we normally call "CLI" (command line interface) irrespective of it triggering and running commands in the background.

Comment: And sorry, I couldn't identify the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new screenshot tool is not anymore a separate utility, but is part of Gnome Shell. Like other Gnome Shell components, it may internally be addressed using obscure and hardly undocumented dbus calls. However, a security model is now in place where these calls are considered "private" and by default not anymore accessible from outside calls.

The default screenshot tool in Gnome Shell has no dedicated name.

Comment: +1 for "obscure and hardly undocumented dbus calls"